# Visual studio 2017 debug code from remote docker

Tags: .net, docker, visual-studio-2017, remote-debugging

I have two machine one with VS 2017 CE. In this machine Virtualization won't support and the another has Virtualization support but with limited memory.

Now I want debug a docker based application using the machine II for docker and machine I for VS 2017 and source.

Is it possible. The application I'm trying to debug is [eShopOnContainers](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers)

Comment: Docker doesn't matter at that point. You'd have to find a way to enable remote debug